# What is big O of this javascript recursion solution to check whether a string is a palindrome?

Tags: javascript, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, palindrome

I found some very helpful solutions to writing a Javascript function that recursively checks whether a string is a palindrome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567811/recursive-palindrome-check-with-javascript). I would like to know what the time and space complexity of the following solution would be. Can you explain how each line contributes to big O?

```
function isPalindrome(string) {
    if (string.length < 2) return true;
    if (string[0] === string[string.length - 1]) {
        return isPalindrome(string.slice(1, string.length - 1))
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Depends on how efficiently `string.slice` is implemented. It might be anywhere between `O(n)` and `O(n²)`.

Comment: No, we can't explain big O in detail. Can you show us your attempt at deriving the big O of the function, so that we can fill in the gaps?

Comment: @Bergi is the variance between `O(n)` and `O(n²)` based on the JS engine's implementation of `slice`?

Comment: @Abdul Yes. (Also, it's important to state that it is the worst case complexity, not the average case complexity)

Answer (score 2):

At first it would seem that your function is O(n), because you call it recursively n/2 times. However, in each call you also use `string.slice`, which has a complexity of O(n). Because of that, your function is actually O(n^2)

Comment: "*which has a complexity of O(n)*" - how do you know?

Comment: I completely forgot to take `slice` into account! However, Bergi's comment still stands : how do you know it's O(n)?

Comment: Well, I quickly checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22615787/12950351) and since it was accepted I thought it was correct. However you are right, it could be worse depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You recursively call the function n/2 times, where n is the length of the string, since you remove first and last entry of the string at each iteration.

Therefore, the complexity would be `O(n/2)` = `O(n)`, and you have at most 3 operations at each function call. That would multiply all this by a constant, which does not change the complexity.

EDIT: as noted in comments and another answer, one of these operations is `string.slice`. You need to check for the complexity of this, because it will multiply as well and can change overall complexity. If `slice` is O(1) constant, then overall you'll have O(n). If `slice` is O(n), then overall that would be O(n^2).

For space complexity, you create a lot of arrays. I'll let you the details, but I'm tempted to say it's `O(n^2)` at first sight.

Sketch of calculations : first array is size `n`, then `n-2`, `n-4`, sum that all up with some math summation formulas.

hint : `n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ...` is `n * (n + 1) / 2` which is `O(n^2)`, that should give enough "feel" that this is `O(n^2)` too.

Comment: "*you create a lot of arrays*" - I was assuming that the `string` variable contains a string, not an array :-) For arrays, we know that `slice` is `O(n)` (both space and time avg complexity). Btw, your space complexity calculation doesn't seem to take into account garbage collection.